# Intel PIN: InsertPredicatedCall and INS_InsertCall

Tags: assembly, x86, instrumentation, pintool

The intel PIN manual (section Memory Reference Trace) says:

> We also use `INS_InsertPredicatedCall` instead of `INS_InsertCall` to
>   avoid generating references to instructions that are predicated when
>   the predicate is false [see here.](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/76991/Pin/html/index.html#MAddressTrace)

_

> When the instruction has a predicate and the predicate is false, the
>   analysis function is not called [see here.](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/76991/Pin/html/group__INS__INST__API.html#g446df8cbefd4950b78cba7c9e7346053)

If I want to analyze all instructions that are actually executed, which of the two shall I pick?

I assume `INS_InsertPredicatedCall` but I am not sure because I have seen `INS_InsertCall` more often. But why would somebody use it, i.e., why would somebody want to analyze instructions

> that are predicated when the predicate is false

? Maybe a minimal example of how the two functions lead to different results would be helpful here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, we should use `INS_InsertPredicatedCall` instead of `INS_InsertCall` in your case. It is quite intuitive to distinguish one from the other, consider the following code

```
cond:
  xor eax, eax
  mov edx, 0x1
  cmp word [esp + 0x4], 0x5
  cmovz eax, edx
  ret
```

whose `C` code is something likes

```
int cond(int input)
{
  return input == 0x5 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

If you use `INS_InsertCall` to trace executed instructions of `cond(input)`, then **for any value** of `input`, you observe always the trace:

```
xor eax, eax
mov edx, 0x1
cmp word [esp + 0x4], 0x5
cmovz eax, edx
ret
```

But if you use `INS_InsertPredicateCall`, then for `input != 0x5`, you will observe only:

```
xor eax, eax
mov edx, 0x1
cmp word [esp + 0x4], 0x5
ret
```

since `cmovz` is a predicated instruction, it is executed only if `ZF = 1`.